# Is $_SESSION['session_id'] always equal to $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']?

Tags: php, session

Ultimately, I am trying to understand how best to verify that I am working in the same session as my previous request.

After

```
start_session()
```

Which of the following values will have changed if my session (a) has not expired or (b) has expired.

```
session_id()
$_SESSION['session_id']
$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']
```

Comment: You can have a valid session without cookies.

Comment: just curious. What was the original question that made you question that the current session needs to be checked?

Comment: Edit: `$_COOKIE` is populated after **receiving** a cookie, not necessarily at the moment you set one or start a session. Best is to use the functions without comparing superglobals (like suggested by Norman). Ryan's question is interesting too. Why do you think you need to check the session?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [session_status()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php):

```
<?php
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
      session_start();
    }
?>
```